# Missing documentation for Prism 7 WPF

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-7

When I visit https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/ most of the topics in the left hand navigation menu have no content.  Is there something wrong with the site or is there somewhere else I should be looking.  I am trying desperately to work through converting an older Prism 6 app to Prism 7 and there are so many breaking changes that I am unable to find any documentation to explain what the new approach should be.  Most of the WPF samples on GitHub, also use Prism 6 not 7. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnWsi.jpg)

Comment: Do you actually have to make the upgrade to 7? Do you miss features in 6?

Answer (score 2):

Brian Lagunas, who owns Prism had started working on the docs for Prism 7 on his twitch stream.  But they never got completed, which is why you only see sections defined and no content added

Check out his youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/brianlagunas), there are videos on Prism. He also streams tuesdays and thursdays on twitch.